# Unable to connect mongodb using mongolite library in R studio over SSH tunnel

Tags: r, mongodb, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am facing problem while connecting to MongoDB over SSH tunnel using mongolite library in R studio. Below is the error I get

```
library(mongolite)
con <- mongo(collection = "collection_name",url = "mongodb://username:password@hostname:22/DB")
```

> Error: No suitable servers found (`serverselectiontryonce` set):
>   [connection timeout calling ismaster on hostname:port]

But I am able to connect to local mongodb using user credentials.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `hostname:22`?  mongodb doesn't normally listen on ssh port.

Comment: Is there any other way to connect?

Comment: Evidently this one is not working. Check mongo config, which port and interface it listens on. Use this information to improve the connection string.